# Making a MySQL query return/stop executing after finding the first match

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query `` Select * From `TableName` Where `Id` = @Id Limit 1 `` that executes on a table with hundreds of thousands of records.

`Id` is a unique auto-incrementing primary column and because of that, there can only be one row with `Id` equal to 33 or 69 for example.

How do I make this query return/stop executing upon finding the first match? Or does it do that automatically?

For example like this C# code:

```cs
foreach (var entry in entries)
    if (entry.Id == RequiredId)
        return entry;
```

Comment: Your query automatically returns only one row when your WHERE clause does an equality search on your primary key.. And, it does it quickly even from a large table. (It might return zero rows if there's no matching row in the table, but it will never return more than one row.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the query planner will know to exit after the first match because of the limit keyword and will not resume the full table scan.

If you want to take it one step further, create a unique index / primary key on the `Id` column, that'll make it even faster by not needing to do a full table scan anymore, as the index makes it possible to use faster search algorithms.

Comment: Thanks! I already have `Id` as a unique auto-incrementing primary index.